# Bash auto_complete .out error

Tags: bash, auto-completion

I am using a customized dotfiles from [a github repo](https://github.com/alrra/dotfiles). When I am trying to execute a c++ executable named a.out and try to use `TAB Key` after a.out (for arguments), I get the following error:

> bash: a.out: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".out")

Now I understood that pressing `TAB` calls some arithmetic operator and for some weird reason it operates on ".out". Is this some known bug? How to prevent this from happening???

Comment: If 3rd party software breaks bash completion, that sounds like something you should report to the maintainers of that software

Comment: Yeah I'll file an issue, but in that software's bash_completion points to /etc/bash_completion, so I am not certain if the bug was from his side!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a troubleshooting tip than a solution, but one can try: make sure the (latest) `bash-completion` package is installed and sourced (however, some later, unrelated installed bash completion scripts might've broken the default behavior), e.g.,

```
$ sudo apt-get install bash-completion
$ . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

(Note: `/etc/bash_completion` may simply be a link to or source the above file, in which case that's fine, feel free to use that. The default path to `bash_completion` varies across systems.)

Then see if the same problem continues to exist or not. If this resolves the problem, add the second line to the end of your `~/.bashrc` so that it's set all the time, and/or troubleshoot & remove anything that may be breaking the default behavior.